# choosing n-1 out of n sigma notation

Tags: probability

I have a conceptual (or notational?) question but I will give an example to make myself clear. Say there are $n$ machines, and the probability of machine $1\leq i\leq n$ to not work in a certain day is $p_i$, how can I write the probability of $n-1$ machines not working in a certain day?
If it was the case that $p_i=p_j=p$ for every $1\leq i,j\leq n$ I think it would have been $(\Pi_{i=1}^{n-1}p)\cdot(1-p)\cdot{n \choose n-1}$, but I fail to see how to write it for the case in which the probabilities aren't the same, since the sigma should somehow run on all choices of $n-1$ out of $n$. Am I making things more complicated than they really are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the same as a single machine working (let the machine $i$ with probability $1-p_i$), so

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\left((1-p_i)\prod_{k=1,\\k\ne i}^n p_k\right)$$ or

$$\prod_{k=1}^np_k\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1-p_i}{p_i}.$$